# Menu doesn't expand in Drupal 7

Tags: menu, drupal-7

I have a primary link created and set of links whose parent is the primary link.

I have enabled "Show as expanded" to all of them (tried with first primary also) but yet the sub-menus don't appear in the screen.

How do I resolve it?

I have went through Structure -> Menus -> Main Menu and list links.[image]

Then, I have clicked edit on the About Me link.

[image]

Comment: How do you print the menus ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too!  It took a while but I found the answer: Using the admin menu, go to Appearance / Settings and uncheck "Main Menu" and "Secondary Menu" in the "Toggle Display" section.  Then click "Save Configuration."